# .net registry reading writing

Tags: c#, .net

Can you refer me to some good reference how I can read write  to  registry via .net resources  ?

I checked the site and couldn't find any good information.

Comment: Have you tried reading the .Net documentation on the Registry class?

Comment: Just in case your google isn't working: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at [`Microsoft.Win32.Registry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx). There is an abundance of sample code there. You can also look at [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/modifyregistry.aspx). Lastly, MSDN has a good overview on the [Registry](http://tinyurl.com/y9yst3b).

Answer (score 7):

Check out the `Registry` class in the BCL

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx

Example:

```
using(var key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\MyProduct")) {
  var value = key.GetValue("SomeValueKey");
  ..
}
```