# How to: Create a Key In the Registry (Visual C#)?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, registry

I am developing a windows application in .NET framework, using C#. At the time of application installation I want to write into the registry a certain value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.net registry reading writing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908539/net-registry-reading-writing)

Comment: If you want to write the registry during installation, it will depend on what installer technology you are using.

Comment: Normally your installation program would provide tools for that and you would not write code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key;
key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Names");
key.SetValue("Name", "Isabella");
key.Close();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx