# Copying subcategories in registry

Tags: c#, windows, registry

can someone suggest the best way how to copy content of one subcategory in registry to another?

For example we have:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER.Software.MyProgram.ver_1
```

and running the function check, if there no ver_2, so create ...MyProgram.ver_2 and copy there all content of ...MyProgram.ver_1.

Answer (score 7):

An extension method:

```
public static void CopyTo(this RegistryKey src, RegistryKey dst)
{
    // copy the values
    foreach (var name in src.GetValueNames())
    {
        dst.SetValue(name, src.GetValue(name), src.GetValueKind(name));
    }

    // copy the subkeys
    foreach (var name in src.GetSubKeyNames())
    {
        using (var srcSubKey = src.OpenSubKey(name, false))
        {
            var dstSubKey = dst.CreateSubKey(name);
            srcSubKey.CopyTo(dstSubKey);
        }
    }
}
```

Called like this:

```
var ver1 = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\MyProgram\ver_1");
var ver2 = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\MyProgram\ver_2");
ver1.CopyTo(ver2);
```

Comment: you probably want to specify the flag `DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames` on the `GetValue` call, otherwise you don't do a true copy for `REG_EXPAND_SZ` values

Answer (score 2):

Based on Wallys extension method I implemented an `MoveTo` extension method.

This code also contains an `key.GetParent(...)` extension method which will open the parent key (needed because I use `DeleteSubKeyTree` method to delete the Key after copy succeded.

```
public static void MoveTo(this RegistryKey src, RegistryKey dst)
{
    src.CopyTo(dst);
    src.Delete();
}

public static void Delete(this RegistryKey key)
{
    using (var parentKey = key.GetParent(true))
    {
        var keyName = key.Name.Split('\\').Last();
        parentKey.DeleteSubKeyTree(keyName);
    }
}

public static RegistryKey GetParent(this RegistryKey key)
{
    return key.GetParent(false);
}

public static RegistryKey GetParent(this RegistryKey key, bool writable)
{
    var items = key.Name.Split('\\');
    var hiveName = items.First();
    var parentKeyName = String.Join("\\", items.Skip(1).Reverse().Skip(1).Reverse());

    var hive = GetHive(hiveName);
    using (var baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(hive, key.View))
    {
        return baseKey.OpenSubKey(parentKeyName, writable);
    }
}

private static RegistryHive GetHive(string hiveName)
{
    if (hiveName.Equals("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return RegistryHive.ClassesRoot;
    else if (hiveName.Equals("HKEY_CURRENT_USER", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return RegistryHive.CurrentUser;
    else if (hiveName.Equals("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return RegistryHive.LocalMachine;
    else if (hiveName.Equals("HKEY_USERS", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return RegistryHive.Users;
    else if (hiveName.Equals("HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return RegistryHive.PerformanceData;
    else if (hiveName.Equals("HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return RegistryHive.CurrentConfig;
    else if (hiveName.Equals("HKEY_DYN_DATA", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return RegistryHive.DynData;
    else
        throw new NotImplementedException(hiveName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908539/net-registry-reading-writing) answer the "how to read/write registry" question, and based on that you can do this:

- read "ver_2" key
- if "ver_2" doesn't exist, create it
- if "ver_2" didn't exist above, read each value in "ver_1" key and write an identical value under "ver_2"

Basically, you read a value, write it, then read another, write it, and so on.