# Detect PC Manufacturer in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to detect the PCs OEM Manufacturer in VB.NET?
Not the model of the computer, just Dell, HP, Lenovo, Acer, Packard Bell and so on?

Comment: Not sure if there's a way to do this, but do keep in mind, not every machine will necessarily have an OEM manufacturer.

Answer (score 2):

The response from your BIOS could not be what is expected but you could try with this

```
Sub Main()
    Dim result = GetBiosProperty("Manufacturer")
    Console.WriteLine(result)
End Sub

Function GetBiosProperty(wmiProperty as string)
    Dim result = string.Empty
    Dim mc = new System.Management.ManagementClass("Win32_BIOS")
    Dim moc = mc.GetInstances()
    for each mo in moc
       if mo(wmiProperty) IsNot Nothing Then
           result = mo(wmiProperty).ToString()
           Exit For
       End If
    Next
    return result.Trim()
End Function
```

Notice that this code requires the reference to System.Management.dll and the imports of System.Management namespace.

Answer (score 0):

This site tells you how to change it, but the relevant keys are below.  http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/user-support/change-the-oem-information-in-the-windows-system-properties-panel-to-your-own/

Registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\OEMInformation
```

Value:

```
Manufacturer
```

And this question has advice for reading the registry using .NET: [.net registry reading writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908539/net-registry-reading-writing)